# The best way to have an interactive flowchart inside a webpage?

Tags: html

Some of my users will be creating flowcharts..The idea is that at certain steps, the charts will allow the user to click on the text to go to another chart, or a manual or something.

My task will be to get these charts online.

The idea of hand coding these inside HTML seems crazy, so I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions?

Ideally, I would allow the users a tool to design the charts how they wish, and they could export it to something I could import into my page...They could either create linkable content inside the software, or if the html generated was neat enough I could do this bit myself.

Has anyone else come across a problem like this?

Comment: Thanks Diodeus, this is perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used Graphviz ([link](http://www.graphviz.org)) to create flowcharts in HTML (an example of usage in real world: google wave used it to draw flowcharts in the waves). In the generated flowchart you can include links associated with nodes, edges, titles, etc. When a user clicks on a link, your software can re-render an image with the data of the new flowchart. Can be exported to png, svg, etc so is kind of easy to include it.